# iOS Metal using nested struct

Tags: ios, c, swift, xcode, metal

Using Apple's Metal how do I access nested struct.

I can do the following.

**viewController.swift**

```
struct Point
{
    var x:Float = 0
    var y:Float = 0
    var value:Float = 0
}
```

This is passed to Metal via device?.newBufferWithBytes.

In **Shader.metal** I have.

```
struct Point
{
    float x;
    float y;
    float value;
};
```

Usage of the struct in Shader.metal is easy.

```
point[0].value = newValue;
```

But how do I access the nested struct, for example children in Metal.

**viewController.swift**

```
struct Child
{
    var x:Float = 0
    var y:Float = 0
}

struct Point
{
    var x:Float = 0
    var y:Float = 0
    var value:Float = 0
    var children = [Child]()
}
```

Comment: I don't think what you want is possible, as you can't have struct members be pointers in metal. I asked this same question recently on the apple developer forums: https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/66446  I have to wonder why you would want to represent a child parent relationship in Metal shaders. You should probably pre-calculate what you're trying to do on the CPU or think of some other approach.

Comment: I should clarify that they can't be pointers when passed in from the CPU, I'm not sure about structs as members of structs defined in Metal.